An infinite series of origami puzzles
fold the 3 shapes below into rectangles with two layers of paper everywhere. the white part of the image is the puzzle.
I'm sure you noticed the pattern in the shapes. now extend it and solve all shapes of that pattern. this will need a general solution.
in case it's not clear, the pattern is a large square (side >2) in the center with 4 small squares at the side.

Similar to
ORIGAMI PUZZLES completed version
which is also made by me.

See picture:

 
 The corners of the blue square (which indicates where to fold) are the midpoints of the four long sides of the given dodecalateral (is that a word?).


good job! that's my intended solution too. i'll just assume you found out how to generalise it since it's rather obvious :)

dodecagon! technically, triangles are called "trigons", and quadrilaterals are called "tetragons", but Anglophones hate regularity (somewhat facetiously), so…

And if you don't like the solution given, here is another one!

 

Equally easy to generalize.

cool! i didn't consider this one, but i guess it makes sense if you did another puzzle in my original puzzle book... i won't say which one it is because that would be pretty spoilerly

@Omega_3301 oh I know exactly which one you are referring to

yes ofc you do haha i saw your comment :)
